# How to randomly pick a picture from a folder in discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm not sure on how to randomly pick an image from a selected folder. Here is what I got so far.

```
const fs = require('fs')
const verifcationFile = fs.readdirSync('./samples');
const length = verifcationFile .length;
const getRandomIndex = length => Math.floor( Math.random() * length );


var file = ?

const attachment = new Discord
  .MessageAttachment(`./sample/${file}`, `${file}`);
const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
     .setTitle('A picture!')
     .attachFiles(attachment)
     .setImage('attachment://${file}');

message.channel.send({embed});
```

I am currently using discord.js V12

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
// get array of every file in this folder
const images = fs.readdirSync('./sample');

// get random element from array
const file = images[Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length)];

const attachment = new Discord.MessageAttachment(`./sample/${file}`, file);
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to read all of your files before running the Discord.js callbacks.

```js
// read all files outside of the Discord.js callbacks
const fs = require('fs')
const veriFile = fs.readdirSync('./samples');

// function to randomly select a file
const randomVeriPath = () => 
  veriFile[Math.floor( Math.random() * veriFile.length ]);
  

client.on("message", () => {
  const file = randomVeriPath();
  const attach = new Discord.MessageAttachment(`./sample/${file}`, `${file}`);
  ...
})
```